# How to know if there will be a top header bar in an app

Tags: buildfire

I have been having issues with the header bar that BuildFire puts in place for plugins.  Sometimes the header bar won't be there

[image: without header bar]

and other times it will.

[image: with header bar]

Is there a way to know if a particular plugin has been configured to show a header bar versus showing no header bar?  I cannot find anything in the SDK documentation about this and have not found anything in the BuildFire object that is attached by the SDK.  Furthermore, it seems that in the SDK there is no way to simulate this lack of header bar, which is why this is very confusing.  Without the ability to know if there will be a header bar or not, it makes the UI, in some cases, bad as the sandwich menu will overlap with any elements that were placed at the top of the plugin view in the SDK under the assumption that there is always a bar there.

Answer (score 0):

In BuildFire your "home plugin" will not have a title bar, but your other plugins will. The home plugin is the first plugin that one sees when they open an app.

Comment: So non-home plugins will always have that top bar?  Also, how do I determine if a plugin is a home plugin in my code?  Is there some type of context object that will tell me?

Comment: First, in any plugin you can force it to hide the title bar https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Appearance#buildfireappearancetitlebarhide . Second, while this isnt part of the official SDK and my change at any time. There is a querystring parameter called fid that may help